# ANDROID_ROOT not set

Tags: android

Has anyone met the same problem? Can you tell me the causes of this ERROR and how to fix this problem?

```
 11-20 13:42:51.407: A/asset(25982): ANDROID_ROOT not set
 11-20 13:42:51.407: A/libc(25982): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 25982 (****.******)
 11-20 13:42:56.917: E/Trace(26287): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Comment: If you really need other people's help with this, do not assume that they are going to magically get to know about the context of the problem :)

Comment: I solved this problem... It is caused by a JNI null pointer error.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `Process` then set Environment variables as a parameter, like this:

```
String[] env = new String[]{ "ANDROID_DATA=/data", "ANDROID_ROOT=/system" };
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(MyEXECUTABLE + " " + MyConfPath, env, workingDirectory);
```